# Significance of trace_ext4_request_inode(dir, mode)?

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, ext4

I was looking at code for inode allocation in ext4 code, I came across this function call  trace_ext4_request_inode(dir, mode); but didn`t got its defination anybody knows what is its purpose over here?

Answer (score 0):

That is instrumentation code for [tracepoints](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/tracepoints.txt). They should show up in

> /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace

when enabled or when using ftrace.